# Word for repetition of the same word before and after comma?

Tags: single-word-requests

How do you describe a type of writing in which a word is repeated (e.g. a word written before as well as after a comma), such as:

> - "My point is that we **cannot, cannot** believe in a loving, forgiving, merciful, compassionate God that is exclusive." —[Quora Source](https://www.quora.com/Are-all-religions-interlinked-with-each-other)
> - "He just made the minimum height to ride the roller coaster and he's just an **awesome, awesome** boy." —Example sentence suggested by [@1006a](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/177853/1006a).
> - "His speech is **quite, quite** fabulous"

One of my coleagues suggested the term **[anaphora](https://www.oxforddictionaries/definition/anaphora)** which denotes:

> 1. the use of a word referring back to a word used earlier in a text or conversation, to avoid repetition, for
>      example the pronouns he,
>      she, it, and they and the
>      verb do in I like it and so do they.
> 2. the repetition of a word or phrase at the beginning of successive clauses.
> 3. the part of the Eucharist
>      which contains the
>      consecration, anamnesis,
>      and communion.

I think it's not a word which I am looking for because it refers to the repetition of a word or phrase from the **starting** of a sentence. See the following example of anaphora:

> **Now is the time** to make real the promises of democracy. **Now is the time** to rise from the dark and desolate valley of segregation to the sunlit path of racial justice. **Now is the time** to make justice a reality for all of God’s children.

Comment: I think your second example is a different animal than the first and third. 1 and 3 look like repetition for emphasis, but 2 looks like the speaker is stumbling over the words—it would be weird to emphasize "just" in that sentence, which would have the effect of suggesting that he's *just barely* an awesome boy (compare *he just—just—made the minimum height to ride the roller coaster* and *he's just an awesome, awesome boy*).

Comment: @1006a, completely satisfied with your suggestion. I am going to add this example sentence suggested by you: "he just made the minimum height to ride the roller coaster and he's just an **awesome, awesome** boy."

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrastive_focus_reduplication  ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The technical term is *epizeuxis*:

> In rhetoric, an epizeuxis is the repetition of a word or phrase in immediate succession, typically within the same sentence, for vehemence or emphasis.

<sub>(source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epizeuxis))</sub>

but I must admit I had to look it up. According to [LitCharts](https://www.litcharts.com/literary-devices-and-terms/epizeuxis), it comes from an ancient Greek word meaning "fasten together."

Comment: +1. I'm glad I now know this term. At the same time, I know I'll probably never use it!

Comment: 27 points in scrabble for that word.

Answer (score 4):

[*Palilogia*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/palilogia) or [*palilogy/palillogy*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/palilogy) (synonymous to epizeuxis) also describe this type of repetition in rhetoric.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the term **'[diacope](https://www.thoughtco.com/diacope-rhetoric-term-1690443)'** which refers to:

> the repetition of a word or phrase broken up by one or more intervening words.

Examples sentences from [litcharts.com](https://www.litcharts.com/literary-devices-and-terms/diacope):

> -**Delightful, delightful**, simply delightful.
>
> -"**Love me, love me**, say that you love me." –The Cardigans
>
> -"**Free at last. Free at last**. Thank God almighty we are free at last." –Martin Luther King, Jr.

Comment: This doesn't quite fit the examples in the question, though it's certainly related and an interesting word to know.

Comment: Dang, now I have that song stuck in my head